# Upgrading from 19.04 to the next release version

Tags: boot, upgrade, 19.04

Since 19.04 will only have support til January 2020, how would I upgrade to the next version (19.05 or whatever they label it)? Would I be able to run a terminal command or would I need to reinstall the whole OS from a bootable thumbdrive and save all my data to another storage device first?

Comment: I am waiting for the LTS release of the current ubuntu and I am very sure we would be able to use the terminal to upgrade!

Comment: You'll see an upgrade prompt to 19.10 in the Update Manager window, with an option to click to upgrade. There is no need to reinstall or use the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

It will be called 19.10. (Afterwards 20.04 LTS and following to this: 20.10 and so on) Upgrade-Procedure is always the same. If you're using a Desktop you could follow these instructions: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-upgrading-ubuntu-desktop#0

If you have a Server or want to use the Terminal/Command line : https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html

There is this, quite old, but mostly quite up-to-date thread about this topic: [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)

Comment: 19.10 will be released in October 2019 (that's what the '.10' means). Then you will have three months to release-upgrade from 19.04 to 19.10, after which 19.04 reaches EOL and loses support. The same cycle repeats every six months.